# Show null value (Guid) in Datagrid when value in database is NULL

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, viewmodel

In my database tabel I have a column that can contain a Guid but also can be *NULL*.
In my Viewmodel this field is configured as a Guid and bind to my `DataGrid`.

How ever when I clear the field in my `DataGrid` and thus set the value to null I get an error 'Unrecognized Guid format.' which is correct because a guid can't be null.
But how can I show it as null or at least pass it to the database as *NULL*?

XAML binding:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AttributeTypeValueId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="AttributeTypeValueId" />
```

And my property in the model:

```
private Guid _attributeTypeValueId;

public Guid AttributeTypeValueId
{
    get 
    {
        return _attributeTypeValueId; 
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != _attributeTypeValueId)
        {
            _attributeTypeValueId = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("AttributeTypeValueId");
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Thx!

Comment: Try setting it to Guid.Empty

Comment: Or use Nullable<Guid> if possible

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nullable :

```
private Guid? _attributeTypeValueId;
```

Comment: Hmm, I still get the error even after I changed the prop to Guid? Do I need to change anything in my xaml binding? It should be possible to just leave the field in the datagrid empty. Thx for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of field and property to Guid? should be OK. I just tested it.